# jQuery transition only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I developed a plugin for WordPress to include the functions of this jQuery lib: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/#top - just for learning purposes.

This is my page: http://petoria.de - if you move the mouse over the logo it rotates 360°.

Problem: it just rotates once. I want it to rotate **every time** I move the mouse over the logo. Like in the examples of the first mentioned website.

My code to do the rotation is this:

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '#logo', function() {
  jQuery(this)
      .transition({perspective: '300px', rotateX: '360deg'}, 500, 'ease-out')
});
```

You can also see it in kmt.init.js

a) how to let it rotate every time I move the mouse over the logo?

b) where the heck is the code running the demos on the jquery.transit website?

Comment: You will need to reset the rotation after it has ran (in the callback), otherwise it won't show again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the style after the animation finishes. You can queue the reset, like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '#logo', function() {
  jQuery(this)
      .transition({perspective: '300px', rotateX: '360deg'}, 500, 'ease-out')
      .transition({rotateX: 0, duration: 0});
});
```

This avoids clocking up larger than necessary rotateX values, and feels neater than incrementing the value every time.

Comment: this is even better. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Either you have to reset the rotation (set it to 0 deg again) in the callback of the transition function or you could achieve the same by changing your code to

```
jQuery(this).transition({
    perspective: '+=300px', 
    rotateX: '+=360deg'
}, 500, 'ease-out');
```

the `+=` increments the property's value

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to return to zero degree before you can rotate it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '#logo', function() {
   jQuery(this)
      .transition({
         perspective: '+=300px', 
         rotateX: '+=360deg'
      }, 500, 'ease-out');
});
```

Using relative values will work at this without any more code then the `+=` increments.